# Responsive circles in a row with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to draw 4 circles, being all 4 flex-items, and I need them to scale with the container they are in. I have seen some solutions where `padding-bottom` is used, but I can´t really understand it.

I managed to get the result that I want with specific `width` and `height` in the flex-items. Can anyone do the same but without that and keeping the same structure in my HTML?

[This is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/bq07omsq/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.holder {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.h1 {
  background: blue;
}
.h2 {
  background: red;
}
.h3 {
  background: green;
}
.h4 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="holder h1"></div>
  <div class="holder h2"></div>
  <div class="holder h3"></div>
  <div class="holder h4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the fixed pixels on both the container and items, use percentage instead to make it responsive. You can still use `px` for `margin` and `padding` on the items, since it's under flexbox.

Use a pseudo element with `100%` of `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`, since `padding` is relative to the container's width, so that give you responsive equal width and height items.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.holder {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.holder:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.h1 {
  background: blue;
}
.h2 {
  background: red;
}
.h3 {
  background: green;
}
.h4 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="holder h1"></div>
  <div class="holder h2"></div>
  <div class="holder h3"></div>
  <div class="holder h4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved with viewport units, i.e. "vw".
The width and height of circles can be adjusted in comparison to viewport, if your container is the screen or you can adjust your container in a predictable way.
This works with `flex-direction: column`.
You can put a text with font-size in vw inside the circle and the text will grow and shrink accordingly.

example

```css
    
        .flexbox {
            display:flex;
            flex-drection:row;
            justify-content:center; 
            align-items:center;
            }
    
        .item {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 22vw;
            height: 22vw;
            background-color: RGBA(252, 102, 32, 1);
            border-radius: 100%;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        <div class="item">text</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: An explanation and a live example would greatly improve this answer. It is hard to tell exactly what you are proposing.

Comment: Great, but I think there might be some more missing, the question is asking for four circles, not a circle with text. Could you update your answer to correctly respond to the answer?

Comment: Sorry man, this answer is still not helpful compared to the accepted one.

Comment: Please don't take this personally. I see you're new here and hope that you stick around and continue contributing. SO has a feature where answers by new users are reviewed to ensure quality of new posts. That is what this is. This is clearly not a bad answer and I would not delete it, I was only trying to help guide you to improve the answer. Please be careful when posting answers to questions that are already have accepted answers unless your solution will fully satisfy the question as good or better than the accepted answer.